# How to count groups of rows and display the top/bottom 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, group-by

I realize this is likely to be an easy one, but my SQL is basic at best.

Lets say I have a table containing a list of orders, with `item_id` being one of the columns. I need to display the 3 least (or 3 most) popular orders of item.

I know that I need to group the orders using `item_id` and then count them. Then I need to display the bottom (or top) 3 in descending (or ascending) order. I'm just not entirely sure how to construct a query like that.

Comment: My English is not enough for me to understand "the 3 most popular orders of item". Is it just me?

Comment: Not just you.  I think the OP meant something more like:  "I need to display the three most ordered items."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **Sql Server**:

```
SELECT TOP 3 item_id, COUNT(*) as itemcount 
FROM table 
GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY itemcount
```

And add DESC to order descent

Answer (score 3):

```
select item_id, count(*)
from table
group by item_id;
```

will give you the whole list.

Bottom 3:

```
select item_id
from (
    select item_id, count(*) as cnt
    from table
    group by item_id
    order by cnt
) where rownum < 4;
```

Top 3:

```
select item_id
from (
    select item_id, count(*) as cnt
    from table
    group by item_id
    order by cnt desc
) where rownum < 4;
```

NOTE: this sytnax is for Oracle.  Use LIMIT if you have MySql or TOP if you have sql-server.

ORDER BY will sort your results.  Ascending order is default, so use 'desc' if you want to get the biggest.

GROUP BY (when used with count(*)) will count groups of similar objects

where rownum < 4:  This is oracles was of doing a LIMIT.  It returns the first 3 rows of the query that has been run.  Where clauses are run before order clauses, so that is why you have to do this as a nested query.

Comment: @quassnoi:  we edited it at the same time: I rolled your edits back, then included them with mine so that the text I added would be there.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL server:

```
select    top 3 item_id, count(item_id) 
from      table 
group by  item_id 
order by  count(item_id) desc
```

will give you the 3 most popular item_id's

using:

```
order by  count(item_id)
```

will give you the 3 least popular item_id's

Comment: What dbms is this answer for?

Answer (score 2):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  item_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    orders
GROUP BY
        item_id
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
LIMIT 3
```